# how can i add a translate button next to any text element in my webpage using php?

Tags: php

```
function translate($from_lan, $to_lan, $text){
    $json = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/language/translate?v=1.0&q=' . urlencode($text) . '&langpair=' . $from_lan . '|' . $to_lan));
    $translated_text = $json->responseData->translatedText;

    return $translated_text;
}
```

i used this code but it returns the following error:

> Notice: Trying to get property 'translatedText' of non-object

Comment: You are using v1, it's deprecated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google translate V2 with curl

```
    $text = 'translated me hello world ';
    $apiKey = '<past your google api key here>';
    $url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2? 
     key=' . $apiKey . '&q=' . rawurlencode($text) . '&source=en&target=fr';
    $handle = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($handle);
    $responseDecoded = json_decode($response, true);

    curl_close($handle);

    print_r($responseDecoded['data']['translations'][0]['translatedText']);
    die;
```